# Why is this file upload script crashing firefox sometimes and does not work in chrome?

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, blob

Well, the following code seems long and complicated at the first look but it's really simple.

Alright, here is my HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="file_select" name="files[]"/>
<div id="upload_button">upload</div>
<div id="message"></div>
```

After clicking the upload button the preupload function is fired. It checks if the file already exists on server and later I'll add some code that enables to continue a cancelled download (checking if parts of the file already are on the server, continues with the first missing part).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var start;
    var stop;                
    $('#upload_button').click(function (evt) {
        var file = $('#file_select')[0].files[0];        
        var chunk_size = 2048 * 1024; //2MB is the size of the parts
        var tot_parts = Math.ceil(file.size / chunk_size);
        preupload(file, tot_parts);
    });
});
```

This is the preupload function that starts the file upload if the file is not on server already:

```
function preupload(file, tot_parts) {    
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file_name', file.name);
    fd.append('file_size', file.size);
    fd.append('tot_parts', tot_parts);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'file_preupload.php',
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#message").html(result);
            if ($("#message").html() == "upload in progress") {                
                fileupload(file, tot_parts, 0, 2097152, 0);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

This is the php script the preupload function is targetting:

```
if(file_exists("uploads/".$_POST["file_name"]) && filesize("uploads/".$_POST["file_name"])==$_POST["file_size"]){
    echo "file exists already";
}
if(!file_exists("uploads/".$_POST["file_name"])){
    echo "upload in progress";
}
```

The file upload function uploads one part after another. After the last part is uploaded the post upload function is fired.

```
function fileupload(file, tot_parts, start, stop, part) {                
    var reader = new FileReader();
    if (file.webkitSlice) {                    
        var blob = file.webkitSlice(start, stop);
    } else if (file.mozSlice) {
        var blob = file.mozSlice(start, stop);
    }
    reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('part', part);
    fd.append('file_name', file.name);
    fd.append('data', blob);
    fd.append('tot_parts', tot_parts);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'file_upload.php',
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log("result" + result);
            console.log("start" + start);
            console.log("stop" + stop);
            console.log("part" + part);
            if (part < tot_parts - 2) {
                start = stop;
                stop = stop + 2097152;
                part++;                            
                fileupload(file, tot_parts, start, stop, part);
            }
            if (part == tot_parts - 2) {
                start = stop;
                stop = file.size;
                part++;
                fileupload(file, tot_parts, start, stop, part);
                post_upload(file, tot_parts);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

This is the matching php script for the file upload:

```
if(!file_exists("uploads/".$_POST["file_name"])){
    if(isset($_POST)){
        $part=$_POST["part"];
        $target_path="uploads/".$_POST["file_name"]."_p4rt_".$_POST['part'];
        file_put_contents($target_path, file_get_contents($_FILES['data']['tmp_name']));
    }
}
```

The last two scripts check if all parts are on the server and put them together again:

```
function post_upload(file,tot_parts) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file_name', file.name);
    fd.append('tot_parts', tot_parts);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'file_postupload.php',
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log('upload successful');
        }
    });
}
```

The php script for it:

```
$part=(int)$_POST["tot_parts"]-1;
$last_part_name="uploads/".$_POST["file_name"]."_p4rt_".$part;
$content=array();
if(file_exists($last_part_name)){
    $file=fopen("uploads/".$_POST["file_name"], "x+");
    for($i=0; $i<=$part; $i++){
        if(file_exists("uploads/".$_POST["file_name"]."_p4rt_".$i)){
            array_push($content, file_get_contents("uploads/".$_POST["file_name"]."_p4rt_".$i));
            fwrite($file, $content[$i]);
        }
    }
    fclose($file);
    $all_parts=glob("uploads/".$_POST['file_name']."_*");
    foreach ($all_parts as $single_part) {
        unlink($single_part);
    }
}
```

The thing is - if firefox not crashes the script works. But every second or third time I'm testing it - my firefox crashes. No javascript errors in the firebug console. It's not working in Chrome. Here's the error from the Chrome console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsBinaryString' on
>   'FileReader': The argument is not a Blob.

Normally should webkitslice work in Chrome. Or what could cause the error?
And how to debug the firefox crash? Any ideas, links or anything else?

Comment: What are you using the FileReader for?

Comment: The line reader.readAsBinaryString(blob); converts the blob in a binary string

Answer (score 0):

First thing `webkitSlice` and `mozSlice` were dropped, you must have taken example from outdated source.

You need to change the below lines

```
if (file.webkitSlice) {                    
    var blob = file.webkitSlice(start, stop);
} else if (file.mozSlice) {
    var blob = file.mozSlice(start, stop);
}
```

You can get chuck using `slice` method by passing the same arguments

```
var blob = file.slice(start, stop);
```

Resources

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob)
- [Article](http://kongaraju.blogspot.in/2012/07/large-file-upload-more-than-1gb-using.html)